# i bought 2 transfers from, this dude. 500 sek each, and he was very weird and rude and, NONE of them have arrived at my account. and i cant seethemOTW

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Transaktion ID:
99d99e805a584712d44d225bd3073ae525784704ec4a531fa4fa0120f42fa7ec
Adress
:
861ikY9sMBsNsuFiWxc7weEBEa17rp66E6GgtbXoi3mwR1PFMzGpvG4coz7pwMdzcHYzhzxCg9qUEEtE4w7ADaB4LVwHrtj
Transaktion nyckel
:
bf9832e4d4af82ff3e6356b5b1936938452c61f2bad621a71904723856b35701

---

Köpande 0.269440103465
XMR för 500.00
SEK med
Swish
(Sverige)
Handels-ID:
f7ca5e08-f035-4201-8a5e-08f0352201db
Skapelse tid:
2024-03-07 16:27 (för 4 timmar sedan)
handel partner:
SafeHouse (592; 100%)
Sett precis nu
Pris/XMR:
1855.70 SEK
Annons handel (online sell)
Du har handlat med den här användaren
Skriv ett meddelande... (Enter: send, Shift+Enter: new line)

LocalMonero krypterar och lagrar chattmeddelanden i 180 dagar i syfte att medla i tvister.
man this shit is giving me nightmares and a hell of a rage problem

Erekobt 2024-03-07 20:28

and now this one says this aswell :- Färdigställd
Denna handel har varit slutförd på 2024-03-07 16:42.
Kontrollera din mottagande plånbok och du kommer att se transaktionen!

Erekobt 2024-03-07 20:24

on the other one it says it was done Denna handel har varit slutförd på 2024-03-07 16:26.
Kontrollera din mottagande plånbok och du kommer att se transaktionen!

Erekobt 2024-03-07 20:23

yea same for me

Erekobt 2024-03-07 20:23

so 2 left

SafeHouse 2024-03-07 20:22

well her it skows 8/10 confirmations

SafeHouse 2024-03-07 20:22

Anknytning:
Screenshot 2024-03-07 at 20-20-31 Trade f7ca5e08 — AgoraDesk.png
SafeHouse 2024-03-07 20:22

or available to see that it its in fact on its way in to the my account you know

Erekobt 2024-03-07 20:20

this one has not either come over

Erekobt 2024-03-07 20:19

almost an hour now

Erekobt 2024-03-07 17:17

still cant see anything coming over anywhere brother

Erekobt 2024-03-07 17:17

yes

SafeHouse 2024-03-07 17:02

both of them?

Erekobt 2024-03-07 17:01

perfekto

Erekobt 2024-03-07 17:01

i released. trade done

SafeHouse 2024-03-07 17:01

been 30 min now and the coins have not even left ur "Väntar på överföring till säljarens icke-förvarsskyldiga plånbok ..."

Erekobt 2024-03-07 17:00

Färdigställd
Denna handel har varit slutförd på 2024-03-07 16:42.
Kontrollera din mottagande plånbok och du kommer att se transaktionen!

---

https://localmonero.co/blocks/tx/99d99e805a584712d44d225bd3073ae525784704ec4a531fa4fa0120f42fa7ec?txprvkey=bf9832e4d4af82ff3e6356b5b1936938452c61f2bad621a71904723856b35701&xmraddress=861ikY9sMBsNsuFiWxc7weEBEa17rp66E6GgtbXoi3mwR1PFMzGpvG4coz7pwMdzcHYzhzxCg9qUEEtE4w7ADaB4LVwHrtj